# python: recursive method understanding

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

What is wrong with what I am doing? In the approach, the control always goes back to the `else` part even after coming to the `if` clause:

```
def recurse(param1, param2):
    is_bool = some_func_that_returns_boolean(param1, param2)
    if is_bool is False:
        return 1 # exit the func
    else:
        recurse(param1, param2)
```

Comment: You *always* call `some_func_that_returns_boolean` with the same parameters. Assuming it's always produces the same output (for the same parameters), then you have infinite recursion.

Comment: No, the function gives different output

Comment: it keep giving `True` until some work inside it makes it return `False` since those param are changing inside

Comment: By the way, `if not is_bool:` rather than `if is_bool is False:`.

Comment: @VLAZ why would I have `return` infront of `recurse(param1, param2)` I want to call it again if the boolean flag is True

Comment: My bad. I misread it. In my defence, I just made myself coffee and I've not finished it.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example that we can run. Provide example input(s) and expected output(s).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `return` to the end of the function to explicily return the value of the recursive function. And better use `if not`:

```
def recurse(param1, param2):
    is_bool = some_func_that_returns_boolean(param1, param2)
    if not is_bool:
        return 1 # exit the func
    else:
        return recurse(param1, param2)
```

Comment: This will likely still be an infinite recursion unless `some_func_that_returns_boolean` has side effects, since the recursive call to `recurse` uses the same parameters.

Comment: this still does not work even when `some_func..` returns True, it still goes to the else part